# Is it possible to disable parameter logging under Invocation details in an Azure Functions app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Under Monitoring for a given function, it shows the invocations. Clicking on a invocation gives you the parameters passed to the function in that invocation. As this data in my case holds personal data, I don't want it stored in the logs or to be available in the Azure Portal. Is there any way to disable this?

[image]

Comment: To suppress all logs, you can use log level None. Plz see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#category-hostresults

Comment: This only solves the application logging, you can still find the data in the Invocation details on portal.azure.com

Comment: You're using PHI as the Partition Key?  Have you though about changing that pattern?

Comment: I don't, just a bad example from my part, but it's in the payload and I don't want it to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do disable the Dashboard logs, remove the AzureWebJobsDashboard app setting. This will prevent all logs going to storage.

Recommend you do some custom logging from your Function using App Insights to have finer control over your PHI.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the solution I was looking for! :)